# Ceph Monitor iptables rules strange behaviour

Tags: iptables, ceph

I'm trying to set up `iptables` for a Ceph cluster. I'm currently putting rules together for one of the monitor servers.

The monitor daemon listens on `tcp/6789` (ip address removed as it is a public address):

```
# netstat -tunlp | grep ceph-mon
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:6789       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2612/ceph-mon
```

If I allow connections to tcp port 6789 and drop everything else the monitor is marked as down by the rest of the cluster:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6789 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Confusingly, if I drop all connections to tcp port 6789 the cluster still operates:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptbales -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6789 -j DROP
```

If I allow connections with a *source* tcp port 6789 and drop everything else the cluster operates:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 6789 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

This doesn't make sense to me, as the daemon is listening on port 6789, so tcp segments should have a destination port of 6789.

If I do a `tcpdump` for source port 6789 I can see incoming packets with a destination port of 56052 and a source port of 6789. This makes even less sense to me as there is nothing listening on port 56052 on the monitor server.

Am I missing something here? I'm using SLES12 and ceph 12.2.7, the FORWARD and OUTPUT chains have no rules, and the policy on all chains is ACCEPT

Comment: You should look for "stateful firewalling" and then "iptables stateful firewalling" documentation anywhere on internet, because you should probably be using it. Once it's understood, you should rephrase the question if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not enabled connection tracking, so when the monitor was trying to talk to other monitors the responses were not being allowed back through the firewall.
I added the following rule to fix the issue:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks to [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) for the suggestion of looking at stateful firewalls.